# How to replace strings with purely numbers as NA?

Tags: regex, r, stringr

I would like to replace strings that contain purely numbers with missing value, NA. I tried the regular expressions, `^`, that matches the start of the string, `[:digit:]` that contains numbers 0-9 and `+` for a match of at least 1 time, but they dont work.

```
> a<-c("1111","A111","DD41412")
> a[a=="^[:digit:]+"]<-NA
> [1] "1111"    "A111"    "DD41412"
```

Comment: side note, if you want to use `[:digit:]`, you need to put double brackets, e.g.: `grep("^[[:digit:]]+$", a)` , else, it will just check for any character put in between the square brackets (so `:`, `d`, ...)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

We can use regex pattern in `grep` and `replace` based on the numeric index (logical index if we use `grepl`) with NA.

```
a1 <- replace(a, grep("^[0-9]+", a), NA)
a1
#[1] NA        "A111"    "DD41412"
```

Comment: thanks arkun, I just liked this answer of yours to appreciate your comment on my question. Unfortunately some people in here are just down voting a question if I don't want to tell all my life story as you seen in that question. however, I appreciate your answer . Thanks

Answer (score 3):

We could also use this:

```
a[!is.na(as.integer(a))] <- NA

# [1] NA        "A111"    "DD41412"
```